# Update only day portion of SQL Date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a field with random `Date` types, for example:

```
2005-01-08
2001-11-15
1988-05-06
```

I need to change these all to have the same day portion of the date, preserving the year and month. Like:

```
2005-01-01
2001-11-01
1988-05-01
```

How can this be done with plain old SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest way would be using `date_format`

```
mysql> select date_format('2005-01-08','%Y-%m-01') as fday ;
+------------+
| fday       |
+------------+
| 2005-01-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

So the update command becomes

```
update table_name
set date_col = date_format(date_col,'%Y-%m-01') ;
```